# Plausible reason why the demons of Hell would be given modern weapons while angels use arrows?

Tags: magic, alternate-reality

In the depths of Hell, the rebellion is stirring. The demon guardians of Hell have been exceptionally cruel to the inhabitants for  millennium. But finally, humans have rebelled and started killing the demons and stealing their weaponry, which includes AK-47s, RPGs, and machine guns. When they invade the castle of Damnatio, and find Helicopters, artillery and tanks. Tired of the depressing decor down in the Underworld, the blown down the gates and march to Heaven. Satan and his herald demons have retreated to the Deepest part of Hell to hide, and the human army, of 38 billion damned souls, are marching to invade the sky.

A messenger angel catches word fo this, and sends word to heaven. The heaven guards aren’t as well armed as the Demons, with bows and arrows and swords. My question is: Why would they give the Demons automatic rifles, but give the Angels only arrows?

Comment: @Ash: No, I never said the angels couldn’t use air superiority

Comment: @Ash, that question is not very similar, and answers from it are extremely unlikely to be valid answers to this question.  Therefore, I don't believe it is a dupe.

Comment: @Ash: the two questions are likely to garner very different answers. One is about weaponry, the other tactics. One gives no details on the abilities of angels and demons (they may very well be identical in terms of ability) the other supposes they have vastly different abilities. There are very few answers to that question that are applicable here.

Comment: The top answer on the other question makes no mention of tradition, but rather talks about ways to nullify the advantage offered by flight.  That would clearly not be a valid answer to this question, and no reasonable amount of editing would make it a valid answer to this question.  Therefore, I do not believe this question is a duplicate.

Comment: This reminds me of Ralph Bakshi's movie *[Wizards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizards_(film))*, where the bad guys have energy weapons and the good guys faerie magic.  In the end, the Luger pistol won the day (the abuse of technology always triumphs over the philosophy of peace).

Comment: However, there's something not right about this question.  Are we to believe that the forces of good have kept the better armed forces of evil at bay all these millenia?  If so, you need to tell us how they did that so that we understand the powerbase of heaven in your world.  As it stands, your question would be better asked, "Given that Hell is so much better armed than heaven, why wasn't there a hostile takeover of Heaven shortly after the Industrial Revolution?"  Your human rebellion is irrelevant without that data.

Comment: @JBH: The demons were planning on a revolt, when the humans beat them to it. And in Hell, the Demons are payed on piles and piles of gold by heaven to stop revolt, so they see no need to at the moment.

Comment: Same reason the Vatican is guarded by Swiss mercenaries with pikes?

Comment: This seems either a matter of opinion (since both angels and demons are usually considered supernatural and thus invulnerable), or it's a question about developing plot in an already-constructed world. Either seems off-topic.

Comment: @Davislor, oooh, you mean tradition?  And the back room is actually full of easy-to-grab Uzis?  I love it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Biblically speaking, Angels are WMDs**

In the few scenes in the bible where angels really cut loose and vent some good old fashioned divine fury only one is necessary for the task. In the story of Moses leading up to the exodus the lone angel of death manages a feat of destruction so spectacular yet so controlled that it wiped out all first born children in Egypt. Angels are described as being so terrifying and obviously powerful that people collapse to their knees and beg for mercy simply from glimpsing one. Angels in the bible seem to be limited by the same rules that demons are in that they are only as powerful as god wishes them to be, and only capable of directing said power within the narrow scope of the task god has given them, but the thing is that they seem to be as powerful as god wishes them to be. They are basically walking, talking, sentient ultra-nukes channeling the power of the creator of the universe as he deems fit. They don't need special weapons because *they already are weapons!* Any weapons an angel carries are purely symbolic of that angel's warlike duties, they are not needed since angels can unmake entire nations by themselves with the caveat that they have no free will and can only perform such tasks when ordered to do so.

**Demon's Really Aren't**

Demons within the bible also follow a similar set of rules, but nowhere in the bible do we see demonic powers manifested quite like the angels do. Demon's are a corrosive influence, they thrive off of the pain and suffering their corruption causes, but do not ever really cause such events themselves. Demons within the bible are limited to the position of tempters and deceivers. They exist to lure man astray and display the evil and cruelty already present within man. Even then, they need god's permission to do what they do. A central theme in the bible is that all power comes from god and that out of all of god's creation mankind is the only one aside from god himself which possesses free will. Demon's exist to prove god wrong and demonstrate what evils and corrupt sadistic sins mankind can wreak with this gift. Even in the end times we do not see the beast Satan himself ever actually destroying anything, he is depicted gathering human followers to wreak his evil for him. Every stage of the destruction and chaos of the end times are not caused by Satan and his minions, but ordered by god to punish the last of humanity who have rejected him.

So, at-least by the central themes of the bible as taught to me as I was raised in a pretty crazy Pentecostal revivalist sect, Satan and angels have no power at all unless it is granted to them by god. A demon's main goal isn't combat with angels, but temptation and deception of man. Angels are seen as mainly messengers and servant's of god who carry his word to his creation. It is very very rare that we ever see angels performing some good ol' fashioned smiting, but when they do they erase nations. They exist as a theme to demonstrate the contrast between mankind's great capacity for faith, righteousness, mercy and mankind's equal capacity for greed, hatred, violence, and sadism. Whenever they are interacting with men they are usually doing so as messengers providing a choice between good and evil.

**Even Regular People can Fight Demons, but Angels Will Mess You up**

To give an idea between men vs angels and men vs demons we actually have a few examples of both. A man named Jacob was told to do something by god via a messenger in the form of an angel. Jacob was a rather ornery and stubborn fella so he jumped on the angel and attempted to put it in a headlock, cuz "no glowing wierdo is gonna tell me what ta do!" They fought at a stalemate for a few days and jacob was feeling pretty smug. "Wimpy angels, I'm doing just fine!" He thought. The angel got fed up and pretty much said "okay, I got other shit to do, enough of this crap" and broke the mighty but thick headed warrior's leg (or hip depending on translation) with the mere touch of a finger, then said "DO I HAVE YOUR ATTENTION NOW? GOOD. GOD HAS A MESSAGE FOR ME TO DELIVER DAMMIT, SO LISTEN UP!" Jacob decided maybe he wasn't so tough anymore and did what the angel told him to do. (paraphrased obviously, the bible isn't written anywhere near that cool.)

Any time demons are encountered in the bible they are basically chased away immediately by normal people who simply refuse to listen to or fear them. The only exception was a gang-possesion of a guy by a group of demons who referred to themselves as legion. Jesus basically made a hand gesture and forced them to infest a herd of pigs then drown themselves essentially just to demonstrate to his apostles what sissy little whiners demons really are. The only time demons are seen performing much impressive acts it is usually because god gave them permission to, or because the victim invited the demon's attention, using their free will to disobey god and losing the protection from demonic forces god has granted. In short, a demon can only really try to convince you to do something, or allow it to do something to/with you. If you ignore it's temptations simply believing in god is enough for literally any one to chase one off.

**So, in summary:**

Demons don't actually use guns and stuff, the followers they have led astray do. Angels don't actually need weapons to do some apocalyptic smiting, any weapons that they carry are simply symbols of their current intent. Since all power comes from god, whichever side he wishes to win will win, and he will grant power and permission to use it to either side that he sees fit. The wild card is humanity because we are the only beings besides himself which posses free choice.

Comment: Excellent answer. It reminded me of https://www.wired.com/2007/04/old-testament-m/

Comment: The thing that graph overlooks is how effective satan's "pull the strings" method works. Since he convinced eve to eat the apple, thus planting evil things like jealousy in her son cain's heart (who would go on to invent murder). Satan doesnt kill you, he convinces you to kill for him, and his meddling literally invented killing. So if you count that..... Satan has a massive death count, literally in the billions. But hes not a trigger-man, hes a puppet master who lets his thralls be the fall guy.

Answer (score 4):

Angels have their traditional weapons because they're *traditional*, Demons as agents of chaos, are changeable and therefore move with the times. The Angels are agents of order and stability they don't pick up the new human fads, why would they, when they can, at last extremity, call on the very **Word of God** to decide the matter. Angels only really have weapons for the look of the thing after all.

Answer (score 1):

The Demons have no qualms in using technology that sprang from the minds of humans, after all: they were responsible for the whole apple of knowledge thing. What does it matter if it’s a blasphemous monstrosity of science? It kills well, so they use it.

Angels, on the other hand, are more orthodox and restrict themselves to the more traditional flaming spears, swords and bows that have been (theologically speaking) Okayed by Management.

Answer (score 1):

Any weapon in the hands of a demon or angel becomes a vessel for their demonic/angelic energy. That energy make up most of the killing power of the weapon. The mechanic properties of the weapon itself become negligible. Which weapon to use is more of an aesthetic choice than a tactical one.

Answer (score 0):

The angels are only guarding the good guys. They don't need decent weapons, their weapons are more for show, hence swords and bows. Swords are also seen as more noble and honourable, which angels generally are too.

The demons on the other hand have to deal with the worst of the worst, and they have no honour or moral guidelines. Every murder, sadist, torturer and rapist ever born (and died) is down there. The demons need some serious weaponry to keep them in line, to prevent precisely this event from occurring.

Answer (score 0):

**The fallen angels like war machines.**

In Hell, there is war - man on man.  Fallen angels are not combatants.  The damned make war on each other and fallen angels are great fans of technology, providing the endless combat the latest and greatest technology for destruction and suffering.

The fallen angels amuse themselves supervising battles of the lost souls and the endless battle is a different form of torment.  But the fallen angels know it is pointless to try to fight Heaven.  They tried before and ultimately were easily defeated.

http://www.dartmouth.edu/~milton/reading_room/pl/book_6/text.shtml
 John Milton's Paradise Lost, and the preface to the Angelic War.

> Or potent tongue; fool, not to think how vain they
>
> Against th' Omnipotent to rise in Arms;
>
> Who out of smallest things could without end
>
> Have rais'd incessant Armies to defeat
>
> Thy folly; or with solitarie hand
>
> Reaching beyond all limit at one blow
>
> Unaided could have finisht thee, and whelmd
>
> Thy Legions under darkness;

If interested, read the account of the battle.  Milton's heavenly host are armed exactly as you describe with spears and swords.  Satan loses the first day, but on the second day of battle, Satan returns with cannons and levels the forces of heaven.  Day 3 does not work out so well for Satan.

Your scenario: when they do talk to the damned, the fallen angels don't talk about the war.  No humans were present for this war and they do not know how it went.  The humans are cocky.  The fallen angels know what is going to happen and so they hide.  They are not hiding from the humans.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps being the inventor of a weapon of war, creating something that is used, and tangentially responsible for, the deaths of hundreds or thousands is enough to put you on the naughty list and damn you to hell...

All the inventors of modern military weapons eventually end up in hell, giving demons a much larger potential arsenal.

Who'd've thought that "thou shalt not kill" would extend to the [military industrial complex](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military%E2%80%93industrial_complex)?